# Error while splitting sheets

Tags: excel, vba

Apologies if this was answered previously and or if the solution is quite simple. I'm getting a

> run-time error '1004', cannot access 'sheet'.

I'm attempting to split a workbook into seperate .txt files.

```
Sub Splitbook()
MyPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
sht.Copy
ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
ActiveSheet.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
ActiveSheet.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
FileName:=MyPath & "\" & sht.Name, FileFormat:=xlTextMac, 
CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
Next sht
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't use `ActiveSheet`. I assume you just want to do `sht.cells.copy`, `sht.cells.pastespecial`, etc.?  Also why are you closing the activeworkbook before finishing your loop? You need to qualify your ranges/cells with the workbook/worksheet you expect them to be called on.

Comment: @BruceWayne, I wouldn't say that. Although `sht.Copy` would certainly do, all other `ActiveSheet` references are needed to reference the active sheet in the just created workbook by `sht.Copy`. For the same reason, the `ActiveWorkbook` at the end of the sub is referencing this latter

Comment: what line is throwing the error?

Comment: @BruceWayne, well, it actually does. as [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-copy-method-excel)

Comment: @DisplayName - That's weird. I knew you were right, but when I tried OP's code, it did not copy the sheet to a new one for me. Weird. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @BruceWayne, I guessed it was Robin messing with your account...:-)

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps - I created explicit references to keep the use of the `Active` sheet/workbook to a minimum:

```
Sub Splitbook()
Dim tempWS As Worksheet
Dim tempWB As Workbook
MyPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    Set tempWB = Workbooks.Add
    Set tempWS = tempWB.Sheets(1)
    sht.Cells.Copy
    tempWS.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    tempWS.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    tempWB.SaveAs Filename:=MyPath & "\" & sht.Name, FileFormat:=xlTextMac, CreateBackup:=False
    tempWB.Close savechanges:=False
Next sht
End Sub
```